# SPTimerv3 keep stopping after a few minutes

Tags: sharepoint-2007

On SharePoint 2007, the timer service stopped after running a few minutes since started. There is two errors in the event log:

1. Event ID 7011, A timeout (30000 milliseconds) was reached while waiting for a transaction response from the SPTimerV3 service.
2. Event ID 7034, The Windows SharePoint Services Timer service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 4 time(s).

## SharePoint log:

```
Timestamp               Process                                     TID     Area                            Category                        EventID Level       Message     Correlation
11/23/2011 20:42:22.57  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0E98)                       0x1198  Search Server Common            MS Search Administration        0   High        CheckForUpgradingAndReturnStatus synchronize logic finds the SearchContext.SearchApplication.IndexServiceInstance is null for ssp 81a16b2b-5ea5-46c6-88f3-b7e16c95861e, the application registry will get removed    
11/23/2011 20:42:22.57  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0E98)                       0x1198  Search Server Common            MS Search Administration        9e53    High        SearchDataAccessServiceInstance.Synchronize(). searchserviceinstance status is bad. Object statuses: ssp status Online sspdb Online searchdb Online ssp search service instance -1 local search service instance Disabled    
11/23/2011 20:42:22.57  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0E98)                       0x1198  SharePoint Portal Server        SSO                             8inc    Medium      In SSOService::Synch(), sso database conn string:    
11/23/2011 20:42:22.62  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0E98)                       0x0C08  Excel Services                  Excel Services Administration   8tqi    Medium      ExcelServerSharedWebApplication.Synchronize: Starting synchronize for instance of Excel Services in SSP 'SSP - myhosted-server.net'.     
11/23/2011 20:42:22.62  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0E98)                       0x0C08  Excel Services                  Excel Services Administration   8tqj    Medium      ExcelServerSharedWebApplication.Synchronize: Successfully synchronized instance of Excel Services in SSP 'SSP - myhosted-server.net'.    
11/23/2011 20:42:22.62  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0E98)                       0x0C08  Office Server                   Office Server Shared Services   6pmr    High        Error getting the administration site for SSP 'SSP - myhosted-server.net'. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The site with the id ccf05a44-6d22-4524-9b23-5e8855086ed7 could not be found.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(Guid id, SPFarm farm, SPUrlZone zone, SPUserToken userToken)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(Guid id)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.SharedResourceProvider.VerifyAdministrationSite()    
11/23/2011 20:42:23.55  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0E98)                       0x0E48  ULS Logging                     Unified Logging Service         8wsw    High        Now terminating ULS (OWSTIMER.EXE, Microsoft.Office.Server.Native.dll)   
11/23/2011 20:42:23.67  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0E98)                       0x0E48  ULS Logging                     Unified Logging Service         8wsw    High        Now terminating ULS (OWSTIMER.EXE, onetnative.dll)   
11/23/2011 20:42:23.67  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0E98)                       0x0E48  ULS Logging                     Unified Logging Service         8wsw    High        Now terminating ULS (OWSTIMER.EXE, ONETNA~1.DLL)     
11/23/2011 20:43:02.06  w3wp.exe (0x0EEC)                           0x10E8  SharePoint Portal Server        Runtime                         8gp7    Medium      Topology cache updated. (AppDomain: /LM/W3SVC/1102933676/ROOT-1-129665176823658565)  
11/23/2011 20:43:03.82  w3wp.exe (0x12AC)                           0x130C  Office Server                   Office Server Shared Services   8z8k    Exception   No administration site found for SSP SSP - myhosted-server.net. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The site with the id ccf05a44-6d22-4524-9b23-5e8855086ed7 could not be found.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(Guid id, SPFarm farm, SPUrlZone zone, SPUserToken userToken)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(Guid id, SPFarm farm, SPUrlZone zone)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.LookupUriInRemoteFarm(SPFarm farm, Guid id, SPUrlZone zone)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.SharedResourceProvider.GetAdministrationSiteUrl(SPUrlZone zone)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Web.AdministrationQuickLaunchProvider.GetChildNodes(SiteMapNode parent) System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The site with the id ccf05a44-6d22-4524-9b23-5e8855086ed7 could not be found.     at M...   
11/23/2011 20:43:03.82* w3wp.exe (0x12AC)                           0x130C  Office Server                   Office Server Shared Services   8z8k    Exception   ...icrosoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(Guid id, SPFarm farm, SPUrlZone zone, SPUserToken userToken)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(Guid id, SPFarm farm, SPUrlZone zone)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.LookupUriInRemo   
11/23/2011 20:43:03.82  w3wp.exe (0x12AC)                           0x130C  Office Server                   Office Server Shared Services   8z8k    Exception   No administration site found for SSP SSP - myhosted-server.net. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The site with the id ccf05a44-6d22-4524-9b23-5e8855086ed7 could not be found.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(Guid id, SPFarm farm, SPUrlZone zone, SPUserToken userToken)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(Guid id, SPFarm farm, SPUrlZone zone)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.LookupUriInRemoteFarm(SPFarm farm, Guid id, SPUrlZone zone)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.SharedResourceProvider.GetAdministrationSiteUrl(SPUrlZone zone)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Web.AdministrationQuickLaunchProvider.GetChildNodes(SiteMapNode parent) System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The site with the id ccf05a44-6d22-4524-9b23-5e8855086ed7 could not be found.     at M...   
11/23/2011 20:43:03.82* w3wp.exe (0x12AC)                           0x130C  Office Server                   Office Server Shared Services   8z8k    Exception   ...icrosoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(Guid id, SPFarm farm, SPUrlZone zone, SPUserToken userToken)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(Guid id, SPFarm farm, SPUrlZone zone)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.LookupUriInRemo   
11/23/2011 20:43:03.88  w3wp.exe (0x12AC)                           0x130C  CMS                             Publishing                      8zug    Medium      PublishingHttpModule.Init() calling AppDomainUnloadListener.Register()   
11/23/2011 20:43:03.88  w3wp.exe (0x12AC)                           0x130C  CMS                             Publishing                      8x0a    High        AppDomainUnloadListener.RegisterSelf() entered lock(this=34622967)   
11/23/2011 20:43:24.63  w3wp.exe (0x12AC)                           0x130C  Office Server                   Office Server Shared Services   8z8k    Exception   No administration site found for SSP SSP - myhosted-server.net. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The site with the id ccf05a44-6d22-4524-9b23-5e8855086ed7 could not be found.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(Guid id, SPFarm farm, SPUrlZone zone, SPUserToken userToken)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(Guid id, SPFarm farm, SPUrlZone zone)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.LookupUriInRemoteFarm(SPFarm farm, Guid id, SPUrlZone zone)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.SharedResourceProvider.GetAdministrationSiteUrl(SPUrlZone zone)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Web.AdministrationQuickLaunchProvider.GetChildNodes(SiteMapNode parent) System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The site with the id ccf05a44-6d22-4524-9b23-5e8855086ed7 could not be found.     at M...   
11/23/2011 20:43:24.63* w3wp.exe (0x12AC)                           0x130C  Office Server                   Office Server Shared Services   8z8k    Exception   ...icrosoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(Guid id, SPFarm farm, SPUrlZone zone, SPUserToken userToken)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(Guid id, SPFarm farm, SPUrlZone zone)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.LookupUriInRemo   
11/23/2011 20:43:24.63  w3wp.exe (0x12AC)                           0x130C  Office Server                   Office Server Shared Services   8z8k    Exception   No administration site found for SSP SSP - myhosted-server.net. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The site with the id ccf05a44-6d22-4524-9b23-5e8855086ed7 could not be found.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(Guid id, SPFarm farm, SPUrlZone zone, SPUserToken userToken)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(Guid id, SPFarm farm, SPUrlZone zone)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.LookupUriInRemoteFarm(SPFarm farm, Guid id, SPUrlZone zone)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.SharedResourceProvider.GetAdministrationSiteUrl(SPUrlZone zone)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Web.AdministrationQuickLaunchProvider.GetChildNodes(SiteMapNode parent) System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The site with the id ccf05a44-6d22-4524-9b23-5e8855086ed7 could not be found.     at M...   
11/23/2011 20:43:24.63* w3wp.exe (0x12AC)                           0x130C  Office Server                   Office Server Shared Services   8z8k    Exception   ...icrosoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(Guid id, SPFarm farm, SPUrlZone zone, SPUserToken userToken)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(Guid id, SPFarm farm, SPUrlZone zone)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.LookupUriInRemo   
11/23/2011 20:43:28.38  w3wp.exe (0x12AC)                           0x130C  Office Server                   Office Server Shared Services   8z8k    Exception   No administration site found for SSP SSP - myhosted-server.net. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The site with the id ccf05a44-6d22-4524-9b23-5e8855086ed7 could not be found.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(Guid id, SPFarm farm, SPUrlZone zone, SPUserToken userToken)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(Guid id, SPFarm farm, SPUrlZone zone)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.LookupUriInRemoteFarm(SPFarm farm, Guid id, SPUrlZone zone)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.SharedResourceProvider.GetAdministrationSiteUrl(SPUrlZone zone)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Web.AdministrationQuickLaunchProvider.GetChildNodes(SiteMapNode parent) System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The site with the id ccf05a44-6d22-4524-9b23-5e8855086ed7 could not be found.     at M...   
11/23/2011 20:43:28.38* w3wp.exe (0x12AC)                           0x130C  Office Server                   Office Server Shared Services   8z8k    Exception   ...icrosoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(Guid id, SPFarm farm, SPUrlZone zone, SPUserToken userToken)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(Guid id, SPFarm farm, SPUrlZone zone)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.LookupUriInRemo   
11/23/2011 20:43:28.38  w3wp.exe (0x12AC)                           0x130C  Office Server                   Office Server Shared Services   8z8k    Exception   No administration site found for SSP SSP - myhosted-server.net. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The site with the id ccf05a44-6d22-4524-9b23-5e8855086ed7 could not be found.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(Guid id, SPFarm farm, SPUrlZone zone, SPUserToken userToken)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(Guid id, SPFarm farm, SPUrlZone zone)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.LookupUriInRemoteFarm(SPFarm farm, Guid id, SPUrlZone zone)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.SharedResourceProvider.GetAdministrationSiteUrl(SPUrlZone zone)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Web.AdministrationQuickLaunchProvider.GetChildNodes(SiteMapNode parent) System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The site with the id ccf05a44-6d22-4524-9b23-5e8855086ed7 could not be found.     at M...   
11/23/2011 20:43:28.38* w3wp.exe (0x12AC)                           0x130C  Office Server                   Office Server Shared Services   8z8k    Exception   ...icrosoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(Guid id, SPFarm farm, SPUrlZone zone, SPUserToken userToken)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(Guid id, SPFarm farm, SPUrlZone zone)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.LookupUriInRemo   
11/23/2011 20:43:39.18  w3wp.exe (0x12AC)                           0x130C  Office Server                   Office Server Shared Services   8z8k    Exception   No administration site found for SSP SSP - myhosted-server.net. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The site with the id ccf05a44-6d22-4524-9b23-5e8855086ed7 could not be found.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(Guid id, SPFarm farm, SPUrlZone zone, SPUserToken userToken)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(Guid id, SPFarm farm, SPUrlZone zone)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.LookupUriInRemoteFarm(SPFarm farm, Guid id, SPUrlZone zone)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.SharedResourceProvider.GetAdministrationSiteUrl(SPUrlZone zone)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Web.AdministrationQuickLaunchProvider.GetChildNodes(SiteMapNode parent) System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The site with the id ccf05a44-6d22-4524-9b23-5e8855086ed7 could not be found.     at M...   
11/23/2011 20:43:39.18* w3wp.exe (0x12AC)                           0x130C  Office Server                   Office Server Shared Services   8z8k    Exception   ...icrosoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(Guid id, SPFarm farm, SPUrlZone zone, SPUserToken userToken)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(Guid id, SPFarm farm, SPUrlZone zone)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.LookupUriInRemo   
11/23/2011 20:43:39.18  w3wp.exe (0x12AC)                           0x130C  Office Server                   Office Server Shared Services   8z8k    Exception   No administration site found for SSP SSP - myhosted-server.net. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The site with the id ccf05a44-6d22-4524-9b23-5e8855086ed7 could not be found.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(Guid id, SPFarm farm, SPUrlZone zone, SPUserToken userToken)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(Guid id, SPFarm farm, SPUrlZone zone)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.LookupUriInRemoteFarm(SPFarm farm, Guid id, SPUrlZone zone)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.SharedResourceProvider.GetAdministrationSiteUrl(SPUrlZone zone)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Web.AdministrationQuickLaunchProvider.GetChildNodes(SiteMapNode parent) System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The site with the id ccf05a44-6d22-4524-9b23-5e8855086ed7 could not be found.     at M...   
11/23/2011 20:43:39.18* w3wp.exe (0x12AC)                           0x130C  Office Server                   Office Server Shared Services   8z8k    Exception   ...icrosoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(Guid id, SPFarm farm, SPUrlZone zone, SPUserToken userToken)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(Guid id, SPFarm farm, SPUrlZone zone)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.LookupUriInRemo   
11/23/2011 20:43:45.63  Microsoft.Office.Server.Convers (0x0668)    0x0CC4  Document Conversions            Load Balancer Service           7jhf    Medium      RegisterLauncher called with uri http://myhostedSP01:8082/HtmlTrLauncher     
11/23/2011 20:43:47.89  w3wp.exe (0x12AC)                           0x130C  Office Server                   Office Server Shared Services   8z8k    Exception   No administration site found for SSP SSP - myhosted-server.net. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The site with the id ccf05a44-6d22-4524-9b23-5e8855086ed7 could not be found.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(Guid id, SPFarm farm, SPUrlZone zone, SPUserToken userToken)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(Guid id, SPFarm farm, SPUrlZone zone)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.LookupUriInRemoteFarm(SPFarm farm, Guid id, SPUrlZone zone)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.SharedResourceProvider.GetAdministrationSiteUrl(SPUrlZone zone)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Web.AdministrationQuickLaunchProvider.GetChildNodes(SiteMapNode parent) System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The site with the id ccf05a44-6d22-4524-9b23-5e8855086ed7 could not be found.     at M...   
11/23/2011 20:43:47.89* w3wp.exe (0x12AC)                           0x130C  Office Server                   Office Server Shared Services   8z8k    Exception   ...icrosoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(Guid id, SPFarm farm, SPUrlZone zone, SPUserToken userToken)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(Guid id, SPFarm farm, SPUrlZone zone)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.LookupUriInRemo   
11/23/2011 20:43:47.89  w3wp.exe (0x12AC)                           0x130C  Office Server                   Office Server Shared Services   8z8k    Exception   No administration site found for SSP SSP - myhosted-server.net. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The site with the id ccf05a44-6d22-4524-9b23-5e8855086ed7 could not be found.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(Guid id, SPFarm farm, SPUrlZone zone, SPUserToken userToken)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(Guid id, SPFarm farm, SPUrlZone zone)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.LookupUriInRemoteFarm(SPFarm farm, Guid id, SPUrlZone zone)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.SharedResourceProvider.GetAdministrationSiteUrl(SPUrlZone zone)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Web.AdministrationQuickLaunchProvider.GetChildNodes(SiteMapNode parent) System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The site with the id ccf05a44-6d22-4524-9b23-5e8855086ed7 could not be found.     at M...   
11/23/2011 20:43:47.89* w3wp.exe (0x12AC)                           0x130C  Office Server                   Office Server Shared Services   8z8k    Exception   ...icrosoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(Guid id, SPFarm farm, SPUrlZone zone, SPUserToken userToken)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(Guid id, SPFarm farm, SPUrlZone zone)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.LookupUriInRemo   
11/23/2011 20:44:02.05  w3wp.exe (0x0EEC)                           0x10E8  SharePoint Portal Server        Runtime                         8gp7    Medium      Topology cache updated. (AppDomain: /LM/W3SVC/1102933676/ROOT-1-129665176823658565)  
11/23/2011 20:44:55.37  w3wp.exe (0x0EEC)                           0x10C0  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         0   Medium      Entering MRU trim routine.   
11/23/2011 20:44:55.37  w3wp.exe (0x0EEC)                           0x10C0  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         0   Medium      Initial table size: 44540730 in 220 entries  
11/23/2011 20:44:55.37  w3wp.exe (0x0EEC)                           0x10C0  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         0   Medium      Final table size: 44540730 in 220 entries    
11/23/2011 20:44:55.37  w3wp.exe (0x0EEC)                           0x10C0  Windows SharePoint Services     General                         0   Medium      Exiting MRU trim routine.
```

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I found the cause. It was due to an ill-configured FBA membership provider.